# Shop page equal height for products with no price

Tags: css, wordpress

I have a problem.
[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rvH1v.png)

The product buttons(with no price) are not aligned with the ones who have price. How could I achieve for the buttons to be bottom aligned?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hi and welcome to StackOverflow. Please refer to https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask on how to ask a proper question and improve yours according the guidelines. As a first step, please add the code you already tried as a https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and describe how it doesnt work for you.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Hello Christian Pavuna,

For equal height or height alignment you have to use a js library like [matchHeight](https://github.com/liabru/jquery-match-height)

```
$('.item_wrap').matchHeight({ property: 'min-height' });
```

change the .item_wrap class to you product wrapper class. Or check their docs for different implementation.